# VB6 program crashing during DoEvents, why?

Tags: vb6, doevents

I have a printing application that is using the Printer object to print files.  On one particular machine (not others), this program will crash after processing some number of files (20 or so).

The crashes always occur during a DoEvents call.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Thanks!

Comment: As DoEvents allows the operating system to process other events, the error could be generated by another event, maybe related to the printing object?

What is it your print object is doing while you execute DoEvents?

When DoEvents is called and another event throws an unmanaged error, the hosting application will crash.

Do you have a OnError Goto in the method containing the DoEvent call?
If not, can you add one and check if the error handler is executed or if it still just crash the application?

All just speculation on my part off course.

Comment: Can you tell us the error message?

Comment: I do have an OnError GoTo in the Sub that is calling DoEvents.  The error handler is never executed.

Comment: Also, there is no error message.  The program just goes away.  I believe on one occasion, the standard dialog that allows you to report the problem to windows appears.  Whenever the crash occurs, there is usually an event in the EventLog that reads something like: Faulting application [myapp].exe, version 1.0.0.4, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x04194127.  (That fault address is sometimes different, sometimes the same).

Comment: Are all the machines using the same printer? Have you checked the printer drivers are up to date on this problem machine? It would also be worth checking the versions of the VB6 runtime files.

Answer (score 3):

I would examine the Dr. Watson and mini dump files and find out what exactly is crashing.  On XP this lives in:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Dr Watson

In other versions of Windows, different places.   Load the Minidump into a modern version of Visual Studio with the pdo (debugging symbols) of your program and you should have a pretty good idea of what is crashing.  If you haven't made symbolic debug info, make a build with that.  Also, make sure you are compiling to Native code and not P-Code (sometimes P-Code crashes and you can't figure out why)...

Comment: Thanks, Kris.  Thus far, I only have one mini dump files from one crash, and that was from a version of the program that did not have symbolic debug info in it.  I will still try to load it into VS and see what's going on, though.  I am compiling into native code.

Comment: It's always a pain when you have to do this, but I have learned from experience always create a PDB and put it in your version control.  We have had problems with weird things like apps only crashing with the German version of Windows XP and the like and the only way you can figure out what is going wrong is with the old reliable minidump (which isn't always reliable).  There are options in Dr. Watson you may want to turn on in the client as well,